# Move column value to next rows

Tags: excel, vba, bash, awk

I have following data in excel (txt also):

```
TEST    K-0008  "Production TEST"   0   4016    8.6 0.01
TEST    K-0009  "Production TEST"   0   4803    8.6 0.01
TEST    K-0010  "Production TEST"   0   4803    8.6 0.01
```

and how I could come to format below by using excel-vba or awk (can be something else), appreciate for any help?

```
TEST    K-0008  "Production TEST"   
   0    8.6      0.01
4016
TEST    K-0009  "Production TEST"   
   0    8.6      0.01
 4803
TEST    K-0010  "Production TEST"   
   0    8.6     0.01
4803
```

thanks,
S

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to post their efforts which they have out in order to solve their own problem, so kindly add so and let us know then.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F \" '{
              split($3,arr," ");
              print $1"\""$2"\"\n"arr[1]"\t"arr[3]"\t"arr[4]"\n"arr[2] 
           }' data.txt
```

The issue you have is with the quotation marks around the Production TEST text. you can use awk but use the quotation marks as a delimiter. You can then further split the 3rd separated field into an array to change the order.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach with AWK would be  (presuming your file is data.txt)

```
awk '$1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\n" $4 "\t" $6 "\t" $7 "\n" $5' data.txt
```